# Current track information from streaming audio with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, metadata, audio-streaming, avplayer

I am streaming audio from an Internet source with an AVPlayer object and I wish to get the current "track" information about the currently playing item on the stream. (e.g. "Car Talk" or "Abbott and Costello")

Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691391/is-it-possible-to-read-metadata-using-http-live-streaming-in-the-iphone-sdk) I have tried looking at the timed metadata on the current item. However it returns nil. Below is the output in the debugger having been paused after the stream starts playing.

```
(lldb) po [[avPlayerObject currentItem] timedMetadata]
$6 = 0x00000000 <nil>
```

I've looked at some of the other objects in AVPlayer, but I'm not entirely sure what rabbit hole I should go down.

Thanks!

**Additional Details**

Observing the property as suggested does not seem to work as the value does not seem to change.

The audio stream I am connecting to is hosted by Live365.

When playing the stream in other apps (e.g. iTunes on my Mac), the metadata *is* displayed, so the data is present in the stream in some fashion.

Comment: That data may become available later, hence it is commonly observed using KVO. It may as well just not be available at all. Simply starting the stream and hoping that it would be available seems to be the wrong approach.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I am pretty sure the data is there, as opening the same stream URLs in iTunes shows the data immediately.

Comment: This may be relevant:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5105746/2700842

May need some tweaking though.

Comment: @NickTerry- That seems to suggest the same solution as Till, which didn't work in my case.